# Does OpenCV's undistortPoints also rectify them?

Tags: opencv, calibration

I'm trying to determine the distance between two object by using OpenCV 2.3.1 with two cameras but can't calculate the object's objectPoints (OCV 2.3.1, MSVC++, Windows 7).  I think this is because the image points aren't being rectified before their disparity is calculated.

**I. WHAT I DO FIRST**

**Step 1. Calibrate each camera by itself**

```
int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

Mat cameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
Mat distCoeffs;

vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
cameraMatrix.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;

calibrateCamera(object_points, 
       image_points, 
       image.size(), 
       cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, 
       rvecs, tvecs);
```

**Step 2. Calibrate the cameras together**

```
int numCornersHor = 4;
int numCornersVer = 3;
const float squareSize = 1.75;

Size imageSize = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);
int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;

for(int i = 0; i < pairs; i++ )
{
for( int j = 0; j < imageSize.height; j++ )
{
    for( int k = 0; k < imageSize.width; k++ )
    {
                    objectPoints[i].push_back(Point3f(j*squareSize, k*squareSize, 0));
    }
}
}

Mat R, T, E, F;

rms = stereoCalibrate(  objectPoints, 
                          imagePoints[0],   imagePoints[1],
        cameraMatrix[0],    distCoeffs[0],
        cameraMatrix[1],    distCoeffs[1],
        imageSize, 
        R,  T,  E,  F,
        TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),
        CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
        CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
        CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH +
        CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL +
        CV_CALIB_FIX_K3 +   CV_CALIB_FIX_K4 +   CV_CALIB_FIX_K5
        );
```

**Step 3. Create the rectification data**

```
  stereoRectify(
        cameraMatrix[0],    cameraMatrix[1], 
        distCoeffs[0],  distCoeffs[1],
                  imageSize, 
        R, T, 
        RC1, RC2,  //RC1: Rotation matrix Camera 1
        PC1, PC2, 
        Q,
            CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 
        1,  
        imageSize);
```

**II. WHAT I BELIEVE**

Goal: 
I'm trying undistort and rectify the image points of one object in the image from camera 1 and the image from camera 2 (I do this process twice: once while the clay pigeon's on the launcher and once one frame before the clay pigeon disintegrates)

Method:
I believe that I don't need to use initUndistortRectifyMap then Remap but can instead just use undistortPoints.  I think undistortPoints undistorts the points of interest and rectifies them.

**III. WHAT I DO SECOND**

You can ignore this if my beliefs aren't correct.

```
undistortPoints(launcherC1, launcherC1Undistorted, cameraMatrixC1, distCoeffsC1, R1, P1);   
undistortPoints(launcherC2, launcherC2Undistorted, cameraMatrixC2, distCoeffsC2, R2, P2);   

undistortPoints(clayPigeonC1, clayPigeonC1Undistorted, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1);
undistortPoints(clayPigeonC2, clayPigeonC2Undistorted, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2);
```

The input and output arrays for undistortPoints (launcherC1, launcherC1Undistorted, ... clayPigeonC2, clayPigeonC2Undistorted) are vectors of Point2f objects.

**IV. DISCREPANCY BETWEEN BELIEF AND REALITY**

After all undistortPoints functions are run,

1. launcherC1Undisorted.y does not equal launcherC2Undistorted.y
2. clayPigeonC1Undistorted.y does not equal clayPigeonC2Undistorted.y.

They are up to 30% different.

**V. QUESTIONS**

1. Q1 In addition to undistorting them does undistortPoints also rectify points?
2. Q1.1_yes. Are the values of y supposed to be equal after rectification?
3. Q1.1.1_yes   Can you tell from the code I've included what I'm doing wrong so that they don't?
4. Q1_no  If undistortPoints doesn't rectify the points then how do I rectify them?

Comment: This is a very lengthy question. If you would like to maximise the number of people that manage to read through to the end, I would suggest editing it to the bare minimum - ask "In addition to undistorting them does undistortPoints also rectify points?", with perhaps a minimal further description. Also, can you confirm that you have [read the manual](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints)?

Answer (score 0):

1. `undistortPoints` cannot rectify points because you never give it the required parameter for rectification - and that is the camera's pose relation to the other camera.
2. When you do rectification the proper way, `stereoCalibrate` + `initUndistortRectifyMap` + `remap`, then yes - the y values of corresponding points will be identical.