# Is there a way to interpolate with influenve of columns AND rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

Let us assume we have a Dataframe with randomly placed NaNs (sometimes even only-NaN rows).
Are there **already established ways/methods** to interpolate with influence of **both, rows and columns** *at the same time*? (vectorized)

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, 4),  
                  columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .1)
print(df)

>>          one       two     three      four
0      0.328574  0.460837 -1.242114  0.871454
1     -1.155524  0.911798  0.733518  1.355840
2     -0.482975       NaN -0.688304  0.015186
3     -0.714028 -2.133300       NaN  1.074630
4     -0.789536 -0.330372  1.158331 -0.571878
        ...       ...       ...       ...
99995 -0.030537  0.160436 -2.085611       NaN
99996 -0.690557       NaN -2.499389  0.044560
99997  0.150332 -1.188956       NaN -1.645208
99998  1.124226  0.443667  1.543553  0.469025
99999 -2.084317 -0.056264 -0.389893 -0.743672

[100000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: If you're talking about linear interpolation, it's not necessary.  The rows already have the "increment" from the rows above and below, so interpolating along the row with the values you do have will produce the right value.

Comment: Like an 2D image, you can use interpolation. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39596856/15239951

Comment: @TimRoberts could you clarify what you mean by "increments"? Do you mean something like a "context" alredy included in the values of the row?

Comment: @Corralien  is that possible with the mode's of the pandas function df.interpolate(method='...') ? 
[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)
(or alternatively with [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html( ??)

Comment: If the rows are linearly related to each other, then you can get the proper replacement for a missing value EITHER by interpolating from left and right, OR by interpolating from top and bottom, because the left/right values already include the row difference.  It doesn't work in your example, because 400,000 random values are not linearly related.

Comment: @TimRoberts if they are linearly related but not related enough, e.g only correlated.
Or: if the columns show start-value, minimum-value, maximum-value and end-value for the timestamp, would interpolating along the row make sense?

Comment: Look, the ONLY way you can reasonably fill in a missing value is if you know how the values in the rows are related to each other.  If there is no linear relationship, then you might as well just choose the average for the row, or a random number between min and max.