# Error in radial distortion based on (zoomed in) OpenCV-style camera parameters

Tags: opencv, distortion

Our AR device is based on a camera with pretty strong optical zoom. We measure the distortion of this camera using classical camera-calibration tools (checkerboards), both through OpenCV and the GML Camera Calibration tools.

At higher zoom levels (I'll use 249 out of 255 as an example) we measure the following camera parameters at full HD resolution (1920x1080):

```
fx = 24545.4316
fy = 24628.5469
cx = 924.3162
cy = 440.2694
```

For the radial and tangential distortion we measured 4 values:

```
k1 = 5.423406
k2 = -2964.24243
p1 = 0.004201721
p2 = 0.0162647516
```

We are not sure how to interpret (read: implement) those extremely large values for k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub>. Using OpenCV's classic "undistort" operation to rectify the image using these values seems to work well. Unfortunately this is (much) too slow for realtime usage.

*The thumbnails below look similar, clicking them will display the full size images where you can spot the difference:*

[image: Camera footage]
*Camera footage*

[image: Undistorted using OpenCV]
*Undistorted using OpenCV*

That's why we want to take the opposite aproach: leave the camera footage be distorted and apply a similar distortion to our 3D scene using shaders. Following the OpenCV documentation and this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24231047/16725) in particular, the distorted position for a corner point (0, 0) would be

```
// To relative coordinates 
double x = (point.X - cx) / fx;   // -960 / 24545 = -0.03911
double y = (point.Y - cy) / fy;   // -540 / 24628 = -0.02193

double r2 = x*x + y*y;            // 0.002010

// Radial distortion
// -0.03911 * (1 + 5.423406 * 0.002010 + -2964.24243 * 0.002010 * 0.002010) = -0.039067
double xDistort = x * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r2 * r2);

// -0.02193 * (1 + 5.423406 * 0.002010 + -2964.24243 * 0.002010 * 0.002010) = -0.021906
double yDistort = y * (1 + k1 * r2 + k2 * r2 * r2);

// Tangential distortion
... left out for brevity

// Back to absolute coordinates.
xDistort = xDistort * fx + cx; // -0.039067 * 24545.4316 + 924.3162 = -34.6002 !!!
yDistort = yDistort * fy + cy; // -0.021906 * 24628.5469 + 440.2694 = = -99.2435 !!!
```

These large pixel displacements (34 and 100 pixels at the upper left corner) seem overly warped and do not correspond with the undistorted image OpenCV generates.

**So the specific question is: what is wrong with the way we interpreted the values we measured, and what should the correct code for distortion be?**