# Exact definition of the matrices in OpenCv StereoRectify

Tags: opencv, matrix, transformation, projection

Normally the definition of a projection matrix **P** is the 3x4 matrix which projects point from world coordinates to image/pixel coordinates. The projection matrix can be split up into:

- **K**: a 3x4 camera matrix K with the intrinsic parameters
- **T**: a 4x4 transformation matrix with the extrinsic parameters

The projection matrix is then **P** = **K** * **T**.

What are the clear definitions of the following input to OpenCV's stereoRectify:

- cameraMatrix1 – First camera matrix **(I assume it is the instrinsic K part of the projection matrix, correct?)**.
- R – Rotation matrix between the coordinate systems of the first and the second cameras. **(what does 'between' means? Is it the rotation from cam1 to cam2 or from cam2 to cam1?)**
- T – Translation vector between coordinate systems of the cameras. **(Same is above. Is the translation from cam1 -> cam2 or cam2->cam1)**
- R1 – Output 3x3 rectification transform (rotation matrix) for the first camera. **(Is this the rotation after rectification so the new extrinsic part of the projection matrix becomes T1new = R1*T1old?)**
- P1 – Output 3x4 projection matrix in the new (rectified) coordinate systems for the first camera. **(What is meant by 'projection matrix in the new coordinate system'? It seems that this projection matrix is dependent on the rotation matrix R1 to project point from world coordinates to image/pixel coordinates, so from the above definition it is neither the 'projection matrix' or the 'camera matrix' but some kind of mixture of the two)**

Answer (score 0):

1. **CAMERAMATRIX1** - is the intrinsic K matrix as computed by stereocalibrate() function in opencv.   you got it right!!!
2. **R** is the rotation matrix of cam2 frame w.r.t cam1 frame. Similarily , **T** is the translation vector of cam2 origin w.r.t
   cam1 origin.
3. If you'll look in O'Riley book "LEARNING OPENCV" pg.-434, you'll understand what **R1**(/**Rl**) and **R2**(/**Rr**) are.
               **Rl**=[**Rrect**][**rl**]; **Rr**=[**Rect**][**rr**];
   let camera's picture planes be plane1 and plane2. When stereo rectification hasn't been done , then plane1 and plane2 will not be parallel at all. Also, the epilines willn't be parallel to the stereo camera baseline. So, what Rl does is that it transforms the left image plane to be parallel to right image plane(which is transformed by Rr) and also , epilines on both images are now parallel .
4. **P1** and **P2** are the new projection matrices after stereo rectification. Remember, camera matrix(K) transforms a point in 3d space onto 2d image plane. But P1 and P2 transforms a point in 3d space on rectified 2d image planes.
    
   if you have calibrated a stereo camera rig before and observed the P1 and K1 values, you'll find that they are pretty much similiar if your stereo rig is almost in rectified configuration (obviously within human range)

---

Comment: question: If T = translation vector of cam2 w.r.t cam1, does that mean "If cam1 is at 0,0,0 and cam2 is at 0.066, 0, 0, then T = 0.066,0,0? or would T = -0.066,0,0?