# Difference between undistortPoints() and projectPoints() in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

From my understanding, undistortPoints takes a set of points on a distorted image, and calculates where their coordinates would be on an undistorted version of the same image.  Likewise, projectPoints maps a set of object coordinates to their corresponding image coordinates.

However, I am unsure if projectPoints maps the object coordinates to a set of image points on the distorted image (ie. the original image) or one that has been undistorted (straight lines)?

Furthermore, the OpenCV documentation for undistortPoints states that *'the function performs a reverse transformation to projectPoints()'*. Could you please explain how this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the 3.2 documentation for [`projectPoints()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c):

> Projects 3D points to an image plane.
>
> The function computes
>   projections of 3D points to the image plane given intrinsic and
>   extrinsic camera parameters.

You have the parameter `distCoeffs`:

> If the vector is empty, the zero distortion coefficients are assumed.

With no distorsion the equation is:

[image: projection]

With `K` the intrinsic matrix and `[R | t]` the extrinsic matrix or the transformation that transforms a point in the object or world frame to the camera frame.

---

For [`undistortPoints()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga55c716492470bfe86b0ee9bf3a1f0f7e), you have the parameter R:

> Rectification transformation in the object space (3x3 matrix). R1 or R2 computed by cv::stereoRectify can be passed here. If the matrix is empty, the identity transformation is used.

The reverse transformation is the operation where you compute for a 2D image point (`[u, v]`) the corresponding 3D point in the normalized camera frame (`[x, y, z=1]`) using the intrinsic parameters.

With the extrinsic matrix, you can get the point in the camera frame:

[image]

The normalized camera frame is obtained by dividing by the depth:

[image]

Assuming no distortion, the image point is:

[image]

And the "reverse transformation" assuming no distortion:

[image]